# Why do templates not implicitly instantiate to const or reference types?

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

Consider the following function template with explicit specializations.

```
template<typename T>
void f(T);

template<>
void f<int>(int i) { std::cout << "f() chose int\n"; ++i; }

template<>
void f<const int&>(const int&) { std::cout << "f() chose const int&\n"; }
```

The first specialization can be implicitly instantiated. The second cannot, *even if the first specialization is absent*. This is unlike the rules for function overloading where a function taking `int` or `const int&` works fine (`g()` in linked examples).

Example with a specialization for `int` available. Works.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1680748749f36631

Example with only a specialization for `const int&` available. Compiles but fails to link.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab8b068d3f807837

Why does template type deduction work this way and why was it chosen to work this way? The alternative would be for template type deduction to behave like function overloading.

My understanding is that with overloaded functions, the compiler already knows all the available options but with templates the compiler must first decide what to look for and then see if it can be instantiated. If this is the case, then would requiring the compiler to search for qualified variations on types be an unreasonable demand?

Comment: "Doesn't compile." It does compile. It doesn't link. Anyway, I think all you're going to get here are guesses. I can make a guess myself, but I don't think it would be helpful.

Comment: True about compile vs. link, will edit. Sometimes folks on SO know that which seems impossible to know. I'm hopeful.

Comment: Sorry, must have misread.

Comment: ? `auto x = &f<const int&>;` implicitly instantiates the second specialization.

Comment: For `template<class T> void f(T)`, you can reasonably assume that you're operating on a *local* copy of an object. Sure, you can explicitly provide template arguments, but the default convention for functions with deduction is not to.

Comment: @dyp Is that really considered an *implicit* instantiation?

Comment: Instantiation is the process of building a function/class from a template. When you instantiate the template `template<class T> void foo(T);` for `T == int`, you create a function named `foo<int>`. The expression `&foo<int>` uses the address of a function, hence this function must exist, hence it is instantiated (if it doesn't exist yet). You don't explicitly request instantiation as in `template void foo<int>(int);`, therefore the instantiation is implicit.

Comment: Except for universal reference arguments (`T&&` + lvalue argument of type `Q` -> `T` deduced to be `Q&`), function template argument deduction doesn't deduce reference types. It can deduce cv-qualified types (`template <class T> void f(T& c); const int i = 10; f(i);` -> `T` deduced to be `const int`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the case of no explicit specializations:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T x)
{
    T y = 42 + x;
    std::cout << y;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 1337;
    f(n);
}
```

Template argument deduction never deduces a reference type, because the alternative would be to *always* deduce a reference type. If it did, the above call to `f(n)` would call `f<int&>`, which would make `T y = 42 + x;` ill-formed.

Picking a specialization happens after deduction is complete.

> The first specialization can be implicitly instantiated. The second cannot, *even if the first specialization is absent*.

You can't make `f<int>` absent, you declared it here:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T);
```